# Ionic 3 Angular Chart.js update data

Tags: angular, chart.js, ionic3

I am using Chart.js with my Ionic 3 Angular app. All works fine, except I am unable to refresh the data for the bar that actually changed.

Here is the code:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, 
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Safeway", "CVS", "Walgreens", "Bon Appetit"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Pepsi",
                backgroundColor: "#002F6F",
                data: this.pepsiData
            }, {
                label: "Coke",
                backgroundColor: "#F50000",
                data: this.cockData
            }, {
                label: "V8",
                backgroundColor: "orange",
                data: [83,19,32,34]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Brands'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

A separate button update the data for `pepsiData` array as:

```
this.pepsiData[3] = 80;
```

But this does not refresh the particular bar. The ugly solution I have now is to redraw the entire chart, which looks like a bad solution.

Comment: This is the init function, right? Where is the refresh logic? Where are you triggering refresh?

Comment: I'd suspect you'd need to be subscribing to something and use an event handler to listen to and repaint your chart based on changed data. If it's from a form be sure to use ReactiveFormsModule. You can subscribe to change events and use that to repaint. Without seeing whole solution and when data changes it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Comment: after change data, you need to call `this.barChart.update()`

Comment: thanks @Duannx that's what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the Chart.js documentation, you need to call `chart.update()` if you wish to update the data in your chart after it was created:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Example of adding data and then updating the chart:

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

After you finish changing the data in your update function, you just need to add the update line of code like the following:

```
this.pepsiData[3] = 80;
myChart.update();
```